# Remove DropDownListFor selection when selecting a specific option in another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue with understanding JS apparently. I am new to it and I am trying to get it to work for the following use case:

> If "Healthcare" is selected from the "discipline" dropdown then the option "Private Sector" will not be visible in the other dropdown.

```
<div class="col-md-6 jurisdictionParentDiv">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Jurisdiction, new { @class ="control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.Jurisdiction,
            GlobalLists.JurisdictionList
                .Where(k => k.Key != "Military")
                .Select(
                    k => new SelectListItem {
                        Text = k.Value,
                        Value = k.Key,
                        Selected = k.Value == Model.Jurisdiction
                    }),
            "-- Select --",
            new { @class = "form-control input-sm" }
        )
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Discipline, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                m => m.Discipline,
                GlobalLists.DisciplineList
                    .Select(
                        k => new SelectListItem {
                            Text = k.Value,
                            Value = k.Key,
                            Selected = k.Value == Model.Discipline
                        }),
                "-- Select --",
                new { @class = "form-control input-sm" }
            )
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Jurisdiction').change(function () {
            var el = $('#Discipline');
            if (el.val() === 'Healthcare') {
                $('#Jurisdiction').remove('Private Sector')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do,

```
if ($('#Discipline').val() === "Healthcare") {
    $("#Jurisdiction option[value='Private Sector']").hide();
}
```

Comment: It isn't working..would I need to add a class to the dropdownboxes? Also, is that all you would need in the script? I would think there would need to be a condition as well right?

Comment: It is just a drop down box with numbers. It doesn't remove anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: @mcpanthers22 please post rendered code...I have updated my code. but really can not just imagine just looking at your code provided

Comment: sorry Im new to this forum stuff. What do you mean post the rendered code? All of it?